# Which timeline is Picard set in?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-picard

Given that Romulus is destroyed in Picard mirroring the events of the Star Trek reboot movie, is this timeline following on from that film (i.e there is no Vulcan and Kahn was found far earlier in the timeline).

Or is that a separate timeline and in the galaxy of Picard Nero hasn’t destroyed Vulcan etc. and events have simply continued post Romulus destruction?

Comment: Let's hope a non-canon one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Picard* is [set in the original Prime timeline](https://www.newsweek.com/star-trek-picard-timeline-new-series-fit-next-generation-films-2399-romulans-1483629)

> As Kurtzman told GamesRadar: "[Picard is] in the Prime timeline, we're not in the Kelvin timeline. But the thing that was interesting about that movie is it was the one element of the film that's still in the Prime timeline, because it was the supernova, the destruction of Romulus, and Spock's jump [back in time] that created Kelvin."

While the events of Hobus are still there (the 2009 *Star Trek* depicted them), we never see any mention of Spock, the red matter system, or his traveling back in time. In other words, *Picard* seems to cherry-pick the events of [Star Trek: Countdown](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Countdown), the direct tie-in into the Kelvin timeline. We know this because B4 is non-functional in *Picard*, while B4 winds up as Captain of the Enterprise-E in *Countdown*.

Comment: Hey! A spoiler warning would've been nice there!

Comment: Just a minor point, Picard did retconn *which* star it was that went supernova and it wasn't Hobus.

Comment: @zrajm I think if you don't want spoilers about X then don't go to questions about X on StackExchange

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Does it?  I recall the term "Romulan Supernova" being thrown around, but if Hobus is within the borders of the Romulan Empire then that's like saying "The Klingon Supernova" or "The Federation Supernova", rather than "The Q'onos Supernova" or "The Earth Supernova".  Or, rather, Pompei and Vesuvius being a "Roman Volcanic Eruption", despite not being in the city of Rome.

Comment: In the show it's the star of the Romulus system that went supernova. Retconning the existing semi-canon supernova of Hobus (that formed a fairly major plot point in Star Trek Online, as well as at least one novel and comic book).

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I'm sure zrajm was joking, but the spoiler is for *Star Trek: Countdown*, not *Star Trek: Picard*. ;-)

Comment: @GeoffAtkins The series never makes clear which star went nova, but given that two characters from *Countdown* are in *Picard*, and most of the events depicted are made canon, saying it was probably Hobus is a safe bet

Comment: Something as major as a star going supernova is not just one of those things that would happen in one timeline and not all of them.  It takes millions of years for a star to build up the mass and energy to cause it to nova, that event was on the edge of happening no matter what.  Sending someone back a mere few decades into the past is not going to change that.

Comment: A spolier warning for what? *It didn't happen...*

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Being forewarned by a time-travelling Spock allows them to make contingency plans *slightly* further in advance to evacuate the planet, "reinvigorate" the star (as [seen in DS9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Sight_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine))!), or prepare Red Matter to protect the planet (per original plan that Old!Spock was too late for).  Plus - spoiler alert -  depending on how canon you count STO, (rot13) gur fhcreabin *znl* abg unir orra *ragveryl* angheny...

Comment: @Machavity - No, it doesn't. It's just repeatedly referred to as the "Romulan supernova." Which I picked up to having been a retconn of it being Hobus. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Chronocidal Spock went back to a different timeline. So only that timeline would have forwarning.

Comment: @Chronocidal - Sorry, watching through the series again, and it's explicitly mentioned during the interview Picard gives in Episode 1. "When you first learned that the _Romulan sun_ was going to explode." I knew I picked up that there was a retconn there.