# How many Borg collectives are there?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-picard

At the end of star trek picard season 2 we see

> The Agnes Jurati Borg Queen has been around for 400 years. Did she start her own separate borg faction and does that mean there is another queen in the delta quadrant with the original borg collective still operating and it is just the Jurati borg ship that wanted to join the federation?

Comment: My interpretation, which may be wrong, and that is why I'm not posting this as an answer, is that the events while they were in 2024 resulted in a new timeline, and that Agnes Jurati is the only Borg queen of the only Borg collective of that timeline, and that is how it has been since she first became the queen in 2024. The original timeline may still, after a fashion, exist, and if so, then the original Borg Queen and her collective still exists there, but only there.

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear It's not a new timeline. Picard placing the key in the wall is what established that. Picard also explicitly stated that the bullet holes left in the wall of the chateau by the drones were a part of the original timeline. Picard traveling to 2024 was always part of that timeline.

Comment: Borghood may be one of many endpoints that a technological civilization may attain.  Another seen frequently in Trek is evolving into a non-corporeal state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Picard showrunner Terry Matalas comes [this tweet](https://twitter.com/TerryMatalas/status/1531507889617051648)

> They’re an off-shoot from an alternate timeline that have stayed out of history’s way. They are not the the Borg. I’d imagine the real Borg are licking their wounds still in the Delta Quadrant after Alt Admiral Janeway poisoned them.

The latter part is a reference to a scene from [VOY: Endgame](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm) (ADMIRAL refers to Admiral Janeway)

> BORG [OC]: Voyager has entered aperture eight two three. Access
> transwarp corridor zero nine. Redirect vessels to intercept at
> subjunction
> (The Queen gets an electric shock. The Borg voice becomes garbled.)
> BORG [OC]: Corridor. Nine. Voyager. USS. S zero zero nine
> transwarp transwarp intercept.
> (Things go bang around her. She grabs a stanchion to stay upright.)
> ADMIRAL: Must be something you assimilated.
> QUEEN: What have you done?
> ADMIRAL: I thought we didn't need words to understand each other.
> QUEEN: You've infected us with an neurolytic pathogen.
> ADMIRAL: Just enough to bring chaos to order.

So, based on the tweet, plus Voyager canon, it appears that the Jurati Borg are not the same as the previously known Borg. In other words, there are now two Borgs races.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Does the Jurati Borg part of the Kelvin timeline, Standard timeline (which includes Voyager canon), or new?  If standard, then does the Borg queen ***not*** know the existence of Jurati Borg?  How about the creation of the transwarp conduit at the end of the [Farewell episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode)) (in-universe 2401) which is *later* than what occurs in the [Endgame episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode)) (in-universe 2378)?  I'll be glad to turn this into a question if you recommend so.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The Kelvin timeline only exists in movies. Picard [is definitely in the Prime timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/229847/62709). I would definitely ask more detailed timeline questions in a separate question

Comment: So many loose ends.  ***Spoilers alert***.  1) In the 350 years between 2024 and 2378 why wouldn't the original queen try to assimilate the Jurati race, or why not more original race defected to join the Jurati race; 2) why does the Jurati race not help Voyager to fight against the original race; 3) etc.  Overall I quite like Picard season 2 though, a lot of parallels with the real universe viewed from Christianity.